# Going from Sweden to the US with a London layover, can I take a bouquet of roses?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration

On the second of November I'm going from Sweden to the USA with a stopover in London. I'm planning on bringing a cut roses bouquet with me and wonder if that's possible or will there be any problems?

Comment: This is a great question and a great addition to the site.  I don't understand why someone answered and two people upvoted the answer, without anyone upvoting the question before me.

Comment: @phoog sorry, I sometimes forget that...

Answer (score 8):

If you do it properly, yes.

When traveling,  assume anything that **can** contain bugs should be reported to the Customs Authorities.

[Flowers- Bring flowers into the United States](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1283/%7E/flowers--bring-flowers-into-the-united-states)

> **Can I bring cut flowers for myself or significant other?**
>
> Most cut flowers are able to enter the United States. However, they **must be declared and able to be inspected by an Agriculture Specialist**. If the plant material is found to be propagatable or bug and disease agents are present the plant material will be seized and denied entry.